# Send RDLC in an email using vb.net

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, rdlc

Okay my website generates thousands of PDFs using RDLCs but my problem is sometimes I want to email them but I don't want to attach a PDF to an email. So what I need is a way to generate the report then either convert it into text or html so I can send it as the body of an email.

Also I am using reportviewr version 11

Also I have tried exporting it as a .doc then trying to convert it to text and i have tried to export it to an excel document then tried to convert it and none of it works.

```
    Dim warn() As Warning = Nothing
    Dim streamids() As String = Nothing
    Dim mimeType As String = String.Empty
    Dim encoding As String = String.Empty
    Dim extension As String = String.Empty
    Dim bytes() As Byte

    bytes = rv.LocalReport.Render("MHTML", Nothing, mimeType, encoding, extension, streamids, warn)

    'Only one copy of the notice is needed
    'If Not Directory.Exists(strFilePath) Then Directory.CreateDirectory(strFilePath)
    Dim fs As New FileStream(strFilePath, FileMode.Create)
    fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
    fs.Close()
```

here is the code i'm using but it gives me an error : `Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: format`

Also i know this code works because I use the exact same thing to export the rdlc to a PDF

Comment: Why not use MHTML output which is a standard option?

Comment: check out my edit. Added the code i'm using and the error i'm getting. Is there something i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Apologies -- I assumed that local reports (RDLC) would surely support the same output formats as server reports (RDL).  Sadly, it seems as though the only supported formats for local reports are: _Excel_, _PDF_, _Word_, and _Image_.

Comment: I figured it out thanks though!

Comment: You should consider posting your solution as an answer to your own questions.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I solved my own problem with some Research about bytes.

Here is the code that I used to solve my problem.

What I did was exported the reportviewr as a word document and then converted all bytes to text. Then from that you end up with a whole bunch of gibberish but eventually you will find the text from your RDLC. So what I did was split the string up to where I was only left with the wording from my RDLC.

Review the code below:

```
 Function GetRDLCText(ByVal rv As ReportViewer) As String
    Dim warn() As Warning = Nothing
    Dim streamids() As String = Nothing
    Dim mimeType As String = String.Empty
    Dim encoding As String = String.Empty
    Dim extension As String = String.Empty
    Dim bytes() As Byte
    Dim msg() As String
    bytes = rv.LocalReport.Render("WORD", Nothing, mimeType, encoding, extension, streamids, warn)
    'Word is the only export that contains text from the rdlc
    Dim content As String = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes)
    msg = content.Split("Ù")
    msg = msg(1).Split("Ѐ")

    Return msg(0)
End Function
```

This solution is not for everyone, but it works for what I need it to do.